# Cropped text in button in iPhone using Skeleton

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using Skeleton (http://getskeleton.com/) for simple css - on desktop it's ok, but on an iPhone the text in button is cropped - see picture.

[image]

Here is my simple HTML code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform">
        jojo
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" dir="ltr" id="user_input" />
        <input class="button-primary" value="Go!" type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tdycs7ar/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this has to do with the line-height on your  element, pushing the content down on scaling. This could be tested with a simulator on xcode if you have access to a mac.

The easy solution would be to remove the line-height attribute from the button? It doesn't seem to be required for the styling to work.

Comment: thanks, but to which `"line-height attribute"` do you mean? I have only `class="button-primary"` on the button.

Comment: The input element in your fiddle is also styled by 
`input[type=submit]` (and some other selectors), 
which you can see when you inspect the element. 
The `input[type=submit]` adds the `line-height: 38px` which I expect, is causing your problems. 
Also, your fiddle seems to differ from the image you've added to this tread?

Comment: That's makes no diff. BTW - the `line-height: 38px` is from `skeleton.min.css`